# Does OpenShift Origin source code include Kubernetes source code?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, okd

I'm trying to read the OpenShift Origin source code, I know Origin includes more features than Kubernetes, and someone said Origin has build-in Kubernetes, is that true? I'm green hand, I did not find any Kubernetes code in the Origin project. If Origin and Kubernetes are in different projects, does it mean I need to deploy both of them on server? So confused, can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: what is your end goal . Do you want OpenShift(Redhat ) flavour of Kubernetes or plain Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

[OKD](https://github.com/openshift/okd) (a.k.a Origin) is a distribution of Kubernetes. As such, if you install OKD, you are in installing Kubernetes.

The [`openshift/origin`](https://github.com/openshift/origin) used to contain the main Kubernetes binaries, but they are now in the [`openshift/kubernetes`](https://github.com/openshift/kubernetes) repo, which is a fork of the [`kubernetes/kubernetes`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes) repo, with the OKD layer on top.